# Htaccess 301 redirect with variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am having some problems. I switched over from one e-commerce system to another a while back and this changed the url structure of some of the pages. I was fine with this and set up some rewrite rules. Somehow this has stopped working and I am not sure why.

I need to change

- /product/{Category-Name}/{URL} to /{URL}
- /ecategory/{Category-ID}/{URL} to /{URL}
- /manu/{URL} to /{URL}
- /news/{category-name}/{URL} to /blog/{URL}

I am using

```
RewriteRule   ^/?(product|ecategory)/([^\/]+)/(.+?)\$  /$3  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule   ^/?(manu)/(.+?)\$  /$2  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule   ^/?(news)/([^\/]+)/(.+?)\$  /blog/$2/$3  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule   ^/?(newscategory)/([^\/]+)/(.+?)\$  /blog/$3  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule   ^/?([0-9]+)/(.+?)\$  /$2  [R=301,L]
```

Bu this is not working now and I don't have enough knowledge of htaccess redirects to work out what is wrong. I have been making changes and looking online but I feel like I am going in circles and this is very confusing.

Please, can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Why `$` is escaped?

Comment: yep this was the problem that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the / before the $. This was my mistake from when I think the URLs used to have .html at the end.